# Count lines in csv files and tally by CreationDate in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I've got PowerShell to trawl a server and export a bunch of csv files with two columns, `BaseName` and `CreationDate`.
Each csv file is named as each file type (documenttype1, documenttype2, etc).

What I'm trying to do is have a script tally each csv and count by year the number of files and dump them into a master file.

Hopefully then I'll have a master file that tells me how many of each documenttype I've got per year.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you add sample input, expected output, and show what you've tried so far, you'll stand a much better chance of getting help.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($Type in Get-ChildItem *.csv)
{
    Import-Csv $Type |
    Group-Object -Property { (Get-Date $_.CreationTime).Year } |
    Select-Object @{N='Type'; E={$type.BaseName}}, Name, Count | 
    Export-Csv Master.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

I assume creation*time*, because creation*date* isn't a property of files, but if you calculated/named that, you'll need to edit. Apart from that, it works on .csv files generated with

```
gci -file |group extension |%{ $_.Group|select basename,creationtime|epcsv "d:\t\$($_.group[0].extension).csv" }
```

to produce an output like

```
Type Name Count
---- ---- -----
.exe 2009     2
.exe 2010     2
.exe 2007     2
.exe 2011    15
.exe 2015    18
.exe 2016    23
.exe 2012    26
.exe 2013    32
.exe 2014    39
.gz  2016     1
.gz  2014     1
.gz  2012     3
.gz  2015     4
...
```